# 1's complement operator in C

Tags: c, complement

In the program below, why is `~a` printed in the output as `10`? Why not `-11`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=10;
    ~a;
    printf("complement :  %d\n",a);
}
```

Comment: You need to enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 5):

Because you don't save the result of the complement operation anywhere.

If you do e.g.

```
a = ~a;
```

then you should get a different result.

Or you could simply print the result of the operation:

```
printf("complement :  %d\n", ~a);
```